# Checking command execution status using if condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I am using Powershell version 5.1 on Windows 10.

I have the below code where I am trying to check the execution status, if it works then output as success else failed.

When I run the code, the code works, but it gives an output as failed.

Below is the code

```
if(Enable-LocalUser -Name TEST)
{
    Write-Host "Success"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Failed"
}
```

How can I get a proper confirmation of the command execution? Please help

Comment: the `Enable-LocalUser` cmdlet does not return ANYTHING. [*grin*] from the help for that cmdlet >>> `OUTPUTS - None - This cmdlet does not generate any output.` <<< ///// that means your IF will always test against a `$NULL` and `$NULL` coerces to `$False` just like zero does. ///// instead, run the cmdlet and use something like `(Get-LocalUser -Name $env:USERNAME).Enabled` to test if the account is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $? to check whether the last powershell command executed successfully or not :

```
Enable-LocalUser -Name TEST
if($?)
{
    Write-Host "Success"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Failed"
}
```

If you wanted exception details , then i would suggest try catch :

```
try{
    Enable-LocalUser -Name TEST2 -ErrorAction Stop
    #The below line will only run if enable-localuser did not generate any exception
    Write-Host "Success"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Failed,Due to :"
    $_.exception
}
```

$? Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.([Excerpt from: Powershell Automatic Variables Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: If I need to capture the Exception Message, can I use the above code in try block and catch the exception?

Comment: @RajivIyer I have updated the answer with a version that gives exception details

Comment: Thank you very much for your help